# How to reference variable file which is on internet in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a shell script which was using many variable, so separated them into two files. All was fine while both were local, now both are hosted on some server.
I want user to download only script and not variable file. How do I reference variable file without downloading it?

> variable.sh

```
$test = "something"
```

> script.sh

```
echo $test
```

I want user to download only script.sh and directly run it.

Comment: You can retrieve the variable file from the server using wget/curl within the script. But I can't say this is a good practice

Comment: using curl/wget I need to store them on filesystem, is there something I can do in memory?

Comment: no you don't. you can use process substitution to avoid storing it in the filesystem `. <(curl -sS url_to_variable_file)`

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```sh
curl $URL_TO_REMOTE_SHELL | bash
```

This will retrieve the remote shell as defined by the URL in URL_TO_REMOTE_SHELL.

As proposed by "oguz ismail" this is potentially a bad, bad idea.

If you do this, you are downloading potentially arbitrary code from a potentially an unknown source that runs unguarded on your system. You should be very, very, very, very, very careful doing this.

Also look at running in "protected environments" such as rsh or look at chroot.

Comment: @prashant if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and up vote it? Thanks.